# Обособленные обстоятельства

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь ставить запятые при перечислении обстоятельств? Кроме того, знаю, что нужно согласование "запорно-регулирующей арматурой".

Энергонезависимое решение по управлению ЗРА (запорно-регулирующей арматуры) в автоматическом режиме на удаленных объектах с использованием пневмопривода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужны запятые, обстоятельства же не однородные. Образа действия, места и... наверно, тоже образа действия.

Comment: Да, что образа действия только первое и третье - это я вижу. Поэтому и начала сомневаться.